# Stars sometimes overlap

Tags: bug, chat, design

[See here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42883306#42883306). I'm not sure exactly what has caused this, it appears even worse in the transcript for me.

[image]

Comment: On closer inspection, it seems to be something to do with zero-height messages.

Comment: Someone starred an "empty" message. Looks like the original message was `>&shy;`; a quoted invisible character. Giving messages a `min-height` would fix it I guess